# GradientDrawable's setStroke

Tags: android, android-drawable

This is my first time to ask question in stackoverflow, now I'm confused about GradientDrawable's stroke width,when I use code to set TextView backgroud as following

```
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setColor(fillColor);
    gd.setCornerRadius(roundRadius); 
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor(getColor(Subject.list.get(0).color));
            gd.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
            tvSpecial1Title.setText(Subject.list.get(0).title);
            tvSpecial1Title.setTextColor(strokeColor);
            tvSpecial1Title.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            tvSpecial1Intro.setText(Subject.list.get(0).intro);
```

the result of this method is that the stroke width of the TextView is thinner than use XML,and the XML is defined as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#ff8200" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="1dp" />


</shape>
```

using the XML as following

```
TextView t = new TextView(getContext());
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plugin_movie_item_icon_orange_selector);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.rightMargin = CommonUtils.dip2px(5);
    t.setLayoutParams(params);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    t.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    t.setSingleLine();
    t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff8200"));
    t.setTextSize(10);`
```

these two kinds of method to set stroke width led to different images in visually, the former stroke width is thinner than the latter,Is there anybody help solve this problem,more hearty thanks to you.

Comment: How do you define `strokeWidth` from the first code snippet? What device are you testing?

Comment: When your using it programatically remember to convert dp to px. `TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, strokeWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());`

Comment: the strokeWidth is same with the width defined in XML,which is 1px.All moblie phones show this phenomenon

Comment: @Naveen Dissanayake yes I did it

Comment: Is strokeWith defined as a float?

Comment: the method setStroke(int width,int color),so the stroke width is defined an int

Comment: @ Naveen Dissanayake the method setStroke(int width,int color),so the stroke width is defined an int

Comment: That could be the problem try wrapping `applyDimension` inside a `Math.round`

Comment: @ Naveen Dissanayake yes! it works! Thank you very much! Could you answer my question use the Post Your Answer,then I can accept it,and you can get the repution,hh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `applyDemensions` method inside a `Math.round()`.

```
Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, strokeWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
```